# Specflow 1.7.0 - integration with Visual Studio Team System 2008

Tags: specflow

Does anyone use Specflow 1.7.0 with Visual Studio Team System 2008? There are no Specflow templates available in “Add New Item” window after installation.
Installed previous version 1.6.1 and this time integration works fine. Any idea?

Comment: see also the related thread in the forum http://groups.google.com/group/specflow/browse_thread/thread/86b2e3032b92f298/92c9957d504b7bf2?show_docid=92c9957d504b7bf2

Comment: Same problem here with 1.7.1 - nightly build also fails

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I was thinking it was because of a bad update of the msi version... but no.

Now : I need to create manually a .feature file

edit : 
I have installed cuke4vs
https://github.com/henritersteeg/cuke4vs/downloads

now it's possible to to add features with "Add New Item"
(and in addition the feature file is colored :) )

Answer (score 0):

Most probably found the bug. 
Install the next nightly build from build.specflow.org, I hope it will work then.